# Why the php artisan: schedule run command does not execute the artisan commands?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I run the `php artisan`: schedule run command and it shows the messages saying that the commands are running. However, nothing happens (the events the commands trigger), it did not work, what can it be?

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Console;

    use App\Console\Commands\CheckPayments;
    use App\Console\Commands\CheckSubscriptions;
    use App\Console\Commands\DeleteOperationalLogs;
    use App\Console\Commands\GenerateInvoices;
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        protected $commands = [
            CheckPayments::class,
            GenerateInvoices::class,
            CheckSubscriptions::class,
            DeleteOperationalLogs::class
        ];

        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->command(CheckPayments::class, ['--force'])->everyMinute();
            $schedule->command(GenerateInvoices::class, ['--force'])->everyMinute();
            $schedule->command(CheckSubscriptions::class, ['--force'])->everyMinute();
            $schedule->command(DeleteOperationalLogs::class, ['--force'])->everyMinute();
        }

        protected function commands()
        {
            $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

            require base_path('routes/console.php');
        }
    }
```

After run `php artisan schedule`:

```
Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" payments:check --force > "NUL" 2>&1
    Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" subscriptions:check --force > "NUL" 2>&1
    Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" invoices:generate --force > "NUL" 2>&1
    Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" logs:delete --force > "NUL" 2>&1
```

**Note**: if I run the commands **separately** it works, for example: php artisan payments: check

Comment: You generally don't run `php artisan schedule:run` manually; as unless you're running it at exactly `XX:YY:00` (i.e. exactly on the minute), none of the commands will run. The docs tell you to save this command to a `CRON`, via `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` and let that run them.

Comment: I understand perfectly, so my code is correct I just need to have a cron execute the command?

Comment: Indeed :) Like you said, executing them one at a time works, the `CRON` will just do that in a timeframe you physically cannot (being human and all)

Comment: Hey @TimLewis I configured cron to run the artisan schedule run command but it is not working, what can it be? I sent an email test when the cron is shot and I receive the email, the cron is okay, but the artisan commands do not execute, why?

Comment: Hmm... Hard to say really. Is there anything in your server logs? At a glance `schedule` method looks ok. Maybe add a `\Log::info("CheckPayments::class running...");` (or something similar) in your `CheckPayments.php` file; will get logged to the Laravel log when it's run.

Comment: I put the log in the class constructor and the message checkpayments appeared class is running but nothing happens and gave another error saying "--force" option does not exist in laravel logs

Comment: Ah I see it. Every command has a signature, `protected $signature = example:command`. You need to use that in your `$schedule->command('example:command')->everyMinute();` instead of `CheckPayments::class`. To use `--force`, you'd do `$schedule->command("example:command --force")->everyMinute()`.

Comment: I changed that earlier today, that way you said, $schedule->command('payments:check --force')->everyMinute();

Comment: Ok. Have you defined the `--force` option in your commands? Follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#options for reference (`{--force}` in the signature, `$force = $this->option('force');` in the `handle()` method). Sounds like the commands are being accessed, as the constructor is logging, but actually executing them. If you remove the `--force` option, do they work?

Comment: Without the force it worked, I leave without --force? What does this force influence my command? Could you post an answer saying to take the --force and put the command in string instead of class in schedule-> command ()? That way it will help other people who have the same doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a Command in your scheduler, you can use it's signature, or it's Classname. Each Command in `App\Console\Commands` has the following:

```
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = "example:command";
```

Once the Command is imported into `App\Console\Kernel.php`, in the `protected $commands = [];` array, it can be used in the `schedule()` function, but using `ExampleCommand::class` isn't correct:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
  $schedule->command("example:command --force")->everyMinute();
  $schedule->command(ExampleCommand::class, ["--force"])->everyMinute();
  ...
}
```

The main issue here seems to be with the `--force` option throwing the following error:

> "--force" option does not exist

Many of the existing Laravel commands have the `--force` flag set, which, from the documentation does the following:

> Force the operation to run when in production.

Many artisan commands prompt for input when you run a command, like `php artisan migrate`, that asks

> Are you sure you want to run this command in production?

Since the scheduler is non-interactive, the `--force` flag will override this prompt to "Yes". That all being said, you need to define and handle the option yourself:

```
protected $signature = "example:command {--force}";

public function handle(){
  $force = $this->option("force");
  if(env("APP_ENV", "production") == "production" && !$force){
    if(!$this->ask("Are you sure you want to run this in production?")){
      return false; // or dd();, etc.
    }
  } 
}
```

This is untested, but if `APP_ENV=production` is set in `.env`, and `$force` is `null` (default if `--force` isn't included), then it will prompt for confirmation, and exit if "No" is answered.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but calling commands with their respective FQCN **does** work. I'm using this in production without any issues.

Comment: Oh cool, if that works, then it's an alternative. I think the main problem was that the `--force` option wasn't configured and was throwing an error. I'll make an edit, removing the phrase "You **need** to".

Comment: Yes, that's right. I personally prefer using the class name like the OP used in his question as it won't break if you change the signature of the command. It is also documented by the way, just [below the signature form](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands).

Comment: Nice catch! Definitely been a while since I visited that manual page; didn't realize that was an option, but definitely cleaner and more future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php artisan schedule:work
```