# Schedule: No scheduled commands are ready to run

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I have the following in my app/console/kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('telescope:prune')->daily();
        $schedule->command('synergy:sync')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I added in my crontab:

/usr/bin/php /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/artisan schedule:run

When I run (in console) `php artisan schedule:run` I've got:
"No scheduled commands are ready to run."

How can I fix it?

Comment: Simple; don't run `php artisan schedule:run` manually. If you've set it up in a CRON, you don't need to run it manually. And you'll get that message as you're not a computer, so it's impossible for you to run it at exactly `everyMinute()` on the microsecond (or millisecond). See this other question that was asked recently about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498576/why-the-php-artisan-schedule-run-command-does-not-execute-the-artisan-commands?noredirect=1#comment97742293_55498576

Answer (score 0):

When running it manually you run it on a certain time in a certain minute. When no cron matches that specific minute this is to be the expected output.

By defining it in your crontab as

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

you run it every minute, which will trigger a job when the Scheduler has something to do.

Comment: That didn't work.. The command ```synergy:sync``` had something to do: Send me a mail, but I didn't receive them. 
When I run the command: ```synergy:sync``` in the console I've got the mail. Also the command; ```telescope:prune``` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I gave you an answer why you should not run it by hand: because it gets run every minute by you operating system. Now you are talking about some other command, which might or might not have something to do with the scheduler in Laravel. Please be more clear what your current problem is.

Comment: I wrote in my problem that I added the artisan schedule:run command in the crontab but the scheduler don’t do anything.

Comment: I also added: ```$schedule->exec('echo "Done!"')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/Schedule.log'))->emailOutputTo('mail@domain.com');```. That also don't do anything. And yes I add: artisan schedule:run to my crontab

Answer (score 0):

Laravel was in maintenance mode, scheduler is not working in maintenance mode.